# Gradle Wrapper 4.6 not recognising test filtering parameter

Tags: android, testing, gradle, junit

I'm having trouble filtering tests with gradle wrapper as the --tests parameter is not being recognized:

```
❯ ./gradlew test --continuous --tests "pt.joaomneto.titancompanion.adventure.twofm.TWOFMAdventureStateTest"                                                                                                                                                                                                              

Continuous build is an incubating feature.

> Configure project :
TitanCompanion: 'annotationProcessor' dependencies won't be recognized as kapt annotation processors. Please change the configuration name to 'kapt' for these artifacts: 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.2.0-alpha10' and apply the kapt plugin: "apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'".


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Problem configuring task :test from command line.
> Unknown command-line option '--tests'.

* Try:
Run gradlew help --task :test to get task usage details. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

As you can see, there is no such parameter in the help output.

```
❯ ./gradlew help --task :test                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

> Configure project :
TitanCompanion: 'annotationProcessor' dependencies won't be recognized as kapt annotation processors. Please change the configuration name to 'kapt' for these artifacts: 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.2.0-alpha10' and apply the kapt plugin: "apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'".

> Task :help
Detailed task information for :test

Path
     :test

Type
     Task (org.gradle.api.Task)

Description
     Run unit tests for all variants.

Group
     verification
```

And I'm using gradle 4.6

```
❯ ./gradlew --version                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.6
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-02-28 13:36:36 UTC
Revision:     8fa6ce7945b640e6168488e4417f9bb96e4ab46c

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.9 compiled on February 2 2017
JVM:          1.8.0_162 (Oracle Corporation 25.162-b12)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.13 x86_64
```

What am I doing wrong here? The documentation clearly states that I can use this parameter to filter testing: https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/userguide/java_plugin.html#test_filtering

Can you help me here?

Edit: This only happens in an Android project. Using the same gradle version in a standard kotlin+spring project it works properly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my question after all this time:

The issue comes from the fact that the android plugin uses the test task as an umbrella for more specific tasks and doesn't recognize the `--tests` filter parameter. So the way to solve this is to specifiy the test task needed, which in my case would have to be:

```
./gradlew testDebugUnitTest --tests pt.joaomneto.titancompanion.adventure.twofm.TWOFMAdventureStateTest
```

As explained here: https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line